# How to find which ports depends on a given one when using macports?

Tags: macports

I want to find which ports depends on a given installed port (`texlive` in my case). I found `port deps texlive`, but this is working in the "wrong" direction. How can I do it?

Comment: The [macports guide](https://guide.macports.org/index.html) has a [comprehensive list](https://guide.macports.org/chunked/using.common-tasks.html#using.common-tasks.finddepending) of ways to do this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `port dependents <portname>`. From `man port`:

> `dependents`
>          Lists the installed ports that depend on the port *portname*.

There is no way to search for *all* ports (including those not installed) depending on a certain port.

Comment: This command seems to ignore build-time reverse dependencies. For example, Mercurial requires `py39-setuptools`, but only at build-time. Any way to obtain that information?

Answer (score 2):

```
port echo dependentof:texlive
```

I believe that this will only show you a list of port installed on your machine that depend on the port.